# SQL Count of different records having same name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL so, I have a table that holds records for assigned jobs as for employee, holding hours required to complete the job.

An employee might have a lot records, regarding to different jobs that was assigned. So what I want is to select all the employees and sum their hours assigned in total..

I want an output to display each employee individually and the number of total hours assigned.

Something like: `select username, Count(Hours) from mytable 
group by username`

The query above obviously is not giving the expected output.

Is there/what is the way to do that?

Any help is welcome!

Comment: How is the query not giving the expected output?

Comment: Hint:  `SUM()`, not `COUNT()`.

Comment: Hint2: If two people share the same username, they will be merged together

Comment: To have also total row, you can use group by CUBE(username). This will add anoather row with empty username column and total user hours

Comment: Thank you all. It is Sum and not Count, indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming username is unique, you should replace `count()` aggregate function with `sum()`:

```
select username, sum(Hours)
from mytable  
group by username
```

Comment: If you're going to post an answer, you really need to *explain* how it works. It's the explanations that give Stack Overflow value, not code dumps.